# What does it mean for a country to use another country's currency?

Tags: currency

Argentina's new President-elect is proposing replacing the peso with the US dollar as the country's currency.

What exactly does it mean for country A to adopt country B's currency? And how does it help solve economic problems in country A?

If the country has fiscal problems, aren't they due to macroeconomic issues in their society. Switching currencies isn't going to solve problems of unemployment or supply/demand ratios. If there's government corruption or high crime rates, the US dollar won't fix them.

All the states in the US use the same currency, but that doesn't mean that their economies are the same, and it seems like this would be even more pronounced for different countries.